# In SQL 2005 how do I move the distmdl.mdf and distmdl.ldf files?

Tags: sql-server

I'm migrating my SQL server system databases to a new drive and can't find any documentation how to move this database.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx